# Gatsby Content-Security-Policy

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, content-security-policy, gatsby-plugin

I created a new gatsby project using the [default starter](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/). All I have done after creating the project is npm install [gatsby-plugin-csp plugin](https://github.com/bejamas/gatsby-plugin-csp) and added configurations in `gatsby-config.js` like so:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-csp`,
  options: {
    disableOnDev: false,
    reportOnly: false, // Changes header to Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only for csp testing purposes
    mergeScriptHashes: false, // you can disable scripts sha256 hashes
    mergeStyleHashes: false, // you can disable styles sha256 hashes
    mergeDefaultDirectives: true,
    directives: {
      "script-src": "'self' 'unsafe-inline' www.google-analytics.com",
      "style-src": "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
      "img-src": "'self' data: www.google-analytics.com"
    }
  }
},
```

However when I run `npm run develop` and load `localhost:8000` I get hit with the following error in the console along with a blank, white page:

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
> 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
> www.google-analytics.com".
>
> ```
> at Object../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js
> ```
>
> (commons.js:404)
> at Object.options.factory (commons.js:4439)
> at **webpack_require** (commons.js:3811)
> at commons.js:5147
> at Function.**webpack_require**.O (commons.js:3860)
> at commons.js:5150
> at commons.js:5152

When I add `'unsafe-eval'` to the script-src, the page loads just fine however that is of course unsafe.

What configuration change do I need to make to allow for the page to load without using `'unsafe-eval'` or even `'unsafe-inline'` if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read this error that the `react-refresh-webpack-plugin` is unable to function because of the CSP. `react-refresh-webpack-plugin` is used only during development.

Your best bet is to just set `disableOnDev: true` in `gatsby-plugin-csp`'s options. It's self-explanatory but this will just disable the CSP in development (`$ gatsby develop`). To test the CSP locally just do `$ gatsby build` and `$ gatsby serve`.